# Has anyone got the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow to work initiated from Apex code now 'RSA-SHA256' signing is available?

Tags: oauth2, crypto

This year old thread [Connect apex and Google API using JWT to retrieve Oauth 2.0 token](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13301/connect-apex-and-google-api-using-jwt-to-retrieve-oauth-2-0-token) was started before the Crypto class included the 'RSA-SHA256' signing algorithm. Now that this algorithm is available, has anyone got this flow to work initiating it from Apex code?

The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_sign) says:

> RSA-SHA256 is an RSA signature of a SHA256 hash

The Salesforce [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_US) sample code uses a Java 'SHA256withRSA' that some Googling suggests is similar but may not be the same.

My current attempts result in a response "invalid assertion". This may be a programming error on my part but I am concerned that it may also be a signing algorithm mismatch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I now have this working for the specific case of connecting back to Salesforce from Salesforce. So essentially it is a port of the [Java sample code](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_US) to Apex. So it appears that Apex's RSA-SHA256 is indeed equivalent to Java's SHA256withRSA.

Steps to get this to work were also:

- Create a certificate via Setup -> Security Controls -> Certificate and Key Management -> Create Self-Signed Certificate with a key size of 2048 and use that name in the Apex Crypto.signWithCertificate call.
- Create a connected app via Setup -> Create -> Apps -> Connected Apps -> New. Upload a copy of the cert created in the previous step to that and as a start select all the oauth scopes (you can cut them down later). Also use the "Manage" to add the profile of the User to the connected app.

In terms of using this protocol to connect to other identity providers such as Google, the (draft) spec says that:

> Of the JWS signing algorithms, only HMAC SHA-256 and "none" MUST be
>   implemented by conforming JWT implementations.  It is RECOMMENDED that
>   implementations also support the RSA SHA-256 and ECDSA P-256 SHA-256
>   algorithms.  Support for other algorithms and key sizes is OPTIONAL.

The [Crypto.generateMac](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_generateMac) method appears to support hmacSHA256 (alg "HS256" in JWT) so that might be the right choice in some cases.

**PS**

The Apex code is posted here [An Apex implementation of the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow](http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/09/20/an-apex-implementation-of-the-oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-token-flow/).

Comment: Great work @KeithC, if I could upvote 100 times I would :)