# HTTP Callout from Salesforce to Google Analytics

Tags: apex, integration, callout, bulk-api, httprequest

I want to get some of the data from Google Analytics into Salesforce. I have looked through a series of articles but I couldn't find any step by step guide how to do so, hence I am unsure what approach should I take. 
This is one of the articles I tried to follow: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

I would need to get the data on a daily basis so I was thinking in creating a batch class which performs GA callouts everyday. I don't have much experience in doing so, especially how to work with the GA api.

If anybody has any knowledge how to achieve this in terms of what design approach would be the easiest to implement and could lead me into the right direction or is able to provide some sample code, reference some useful articles I would be grateful.

Comment: This question may already have an answer by Andy H here: [Connect apex and Google API using JWT to retrieve Oauth 2.0 token](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13301/connect-apex-and-google-api-using-jwt-to-retrieve-oauth-2-0-token)

Comment: Yeah, you were right, that's a duplicate, I shouldn't have answered, still not used to all correct procedures, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Alex No problem! Great find and I think it'd be okay to undelete your answer so you get some credit for it. IMO it's okay to answer *and* flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Connect apex and Google API using JWT to retrieve Oauth 2.0 token](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13301/connect-apex-and-google-api-using-jwt-to-retrieve-oauth-2-0-token)

The comment by Andy H. gives you all the needed info to start pulling info out. 
I finished today my project and we're already getting GA info into  our SF org thanks to his explanation on that post.

With that you can get your token, so you only have to go to https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/
and build your query, copy it adding at the end the token you got from the callout you build from the code by Andy H. 
And then you only have to structure the info in the Json you will receive and store it in the objects you find suitable.

Hopes this helps you, if you are still struggling I can share some of my code but most of it it's just the same than his.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is, this question is a duplicate?

Comment: @Alexander Aeons Torn thanks for your answer I will look into the article you posted

Comment: @Alexander Aeons Torn I would require a bit of your assistance if you don't mind with regards to a couple of initial setup configurations.

Comment: Sure Mate, where do are you having doubts?

Comment: @Alexander Aeons Torn Thanks for your reply. Well I followed the steps in Andy's answer but when I try to get the token it gives me System.SecurityException: Invalid Crypto Key error. I created credentials of type Service account keys and got the private_key form the JSON file but I am unsure which part of it should i put since it is on several lines. And for the gmail mail account, do I have to insert the gmail.com or gserviceaccount.com account

Comment: Ok, I had some struggle there too,  You have later when you created already your service account. Go to Google Analytics-> Admin->User Management Add permissions for "dummyname@dummy-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com". The token you have to use to make the call to get the token is quite large and remember to remove the '\n' from it as Andy says. Mine had a 1626 chars length. 

If you still have doubts tell me.

Comment: @Alexander Aeons Torn yes thanks for your answer. Now when I run it says System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup-&gt;Security-&gt;Remote site settings. endpoint = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.  I guess I need to verify the domain first, so I'd need to wait until thursday for that. If I encounter any other problems I'll let you know. And thanks again you were very helpful!

Comment: You have to add this endpoint to Remote sites. After this you should be able to perform the callout ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39227/discussion-between-marc-zaharescu-and-alexander-aeons-torn).