# Is Digital Signature mandatory for the oauth JWT token flow?

Tags: oauth2, authentication, certificates, key, jwt

Is Digital Signature mandatory for the oauth JWT token flow ? If not, how do I implement the flow without the certificate.A web server is supposed to send a request for the access token and I need to implement the flow without the certificate. Please share insights/thoughts/experiences.

Comment: welcome to SFDC! prior to posting a question, we recommend doing some research and asking a specific question in regards to whatever documentation you might have read and refer it in your post. Please take some time to review [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: as per your question, i would recommend reading https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0… at the very least, and if you have specific questions on it, please edit your post. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @glls. I read the above document. I will edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, digital signature is mandatory, as this is a required part of JWT principle. Read [more](https://jwt.io/introduction/) about.

There is an [interesting question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13301/connect-apex-and-google-api-using-jwt-to-retrieve-oauth-2-0-token/174015), where you will find to ways of using JWT: by means of new Auth.JWT class in combination with Auth.JWS, and custom by using basic apex classes